# it takes me out during short time, ASP.NET Login

Tags: asp.net

i wrote a login menu and control panel for users,
but during short time it takes me out, see the codes
you know in the config file i wrote that "Admin" folder is secure and it's timeout is 30 minutes but when i'm logging maybe in 40-50 sec it take me out, where am i wrong ?
please help me
Web.config codes :

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms name="MyAppCookie" path="/" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" defaultUrl="Admin" />
      </authentication>
      <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false" />
      <!--<sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>-->
  </system.web>
    <location path="Admin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="?" />
                <deny users="Users" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Login Menu :

```
var login = (from u in DataContext.Context.Core_Users
                         where u.UserName == txtuid.Text && u.Password == txtPwd.Text
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();
            if(login != null)
            {
                var role = (from r in DataContext.Context.Core_Roles
                            where r.RoleID == login.RoleID
                            select r).FirstOrDefault();
                if(role != null)
                {
                    string RoleName = role.RoleName;
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket AuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, txtuid.Text, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),false,RoleName,FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
                    string encryptedTocket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(AuthTicket);
                    HttpCookie AuthCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,encryptedTocket);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(AuthCookie);
                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(txtuid.Text, chkRemember.Checked));
                }
                else
                {
                    lblMessage.Text = "Role Deleted";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                 lblMessage.Text = "Wrong username or password";
            }
```

And secure pages :

```
if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                //Start Authorization Section
                if (!Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
                }
                // End of Authorization Section
            }
```

Comment: You should hash and salt your passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Sessionstate timeout property is mentioned in minutes

In webconfig file...

```
<system.web>
.......
    <sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState>
</system.web>
```

The session will get expired if the webform is idle for 24 hrs continuously.

You can have this sessionstate block only within .

Comment: i know i put <sessionState timeout="1440"></sessionState> but it wont work and i blocked it, about TimeOut it works in my visual studio but when i uploaded in my host it takes me out :(

Comment: you can try to save your session state in your sql server

Comment: you know i didnt add mechinkey and i had to change cookie name, when i did it works properly. thanks my friends